# Scrapy null output but data was scraped

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I`m scraping a website and trying to save the output in a MongoDB. It seens that the code is ok, but when I tried a simple output (scrapy crawl IR -o items.json -t json) the file comes out blank... But the log of the spider shows that data was scraped...

Here is my spider code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from teste.items import IngressoRapidoItem

class IngressoRapidoSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "IR"
   allowed_domains = ["ingressorapido.com.br"]
   start_urls = (
        'http://www.ingressorapido.com.br/eventos.aspx?genero=55',
         )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = []
        item = IngressoRapidoItem()
        item['banda'] = hxs.select('normalize-space(//a[contains(@href,"Evento")]    /text())').extract()
        item['local'] = hxs.select('normalize-space(//td/span[contains(@style,     "normal")]/text())').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Anyone guess why the output is null even with the data been scraped ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the log look like? Can you upload the contents?

Comment: What happens if you run `scrapy runspider <spider_file_name>.py -o out.json`?

Comment: alecxe, with the command that you told me the output comes out perfect!!! Could you give me further explain and why the scrapy crawl/pipeline aren`t working ?

Comment: i ran your code and getting two entries in json  Is that what u getting?

Comment: i.e "banda": [""], "local": ["Teatro Riachuelo"]

Comment: Actually when I run scrapy crawl IR -o items.json -t json i get an empty item.json file. But if I run like alecxe suggested I get a complete scrap, here is part of it:

Comment: {"banda": ["Beatles Abbey Road"], "local": ["Teatro Riachuelo"]}

Comment: so what is your problem if you are getting complete scrape on json?

Comment: I'm not... when I run crapy crawl IR -o items.json -t json I receive an empty json... If I try a pipeline the output is null as well. The only command that bring me data is scrapy runspider <spider_file_name>.py -o out.json

Answer (score 0):

Having run the code posted above, I can confirm that data was scraped but whether that data was actually useful or not is hard to say as only one item was created with a venue but no event name.

I modified the xpath code a little and was able to return an item for all 10 events shown on the first page of `http://www.ingressorapido.com.br/eventos.aspx?genero=55`. I was then able to write the scraped data to a json file without any trouble.

Let me know if you have any questions, or if the xpath code does not return the required data.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from teste.items import IngressoRapidoItem

class IngressoRapidoSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "IR"
    allowed_domains = ["ingressorapido.com.br"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.ingressorapido.com.br/eventos.aspx?genero=55',
         )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        events = hxs.select('//table[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_dlEventos"]//table//td[2]')
        items = []
        for e in events:
            item = IngressoRapidoItem()
            item['banda'] = e.select('normalize-space(.//a//text())').extract()
            item['local'] = e.select('normalize-space(.//span//text())').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: The code does work, but still no output on json, xml or anything... I thought that might be write permission, but the file is created, with no data...

Comment: Try removing any pipeline references in your settings.py file and run the command again.

Comment: Still empty... Even with the pipeline turned off

Comment: Could you post your settings.py file please?

Comment: With the pipeline turned off: 
BOT_NAME = 'teste'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['teste.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'teste.spiders'